# Hive Update,Insert,delete

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have been trying to implement the UPDATE,INSERT,DELETE operations in hive table as per [instructions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions#HiveTransactions). But whenever I try to include the properties which will do our work i.e. configuration values set for `INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE hive.support.concurrency true` (default is `false`) `hive.enforce.bucketing true` (default is `false`) `hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode nonstrict` (default is `strict`) After that, if I run `show tables` on hive shell it's taking 65.15 seconds which normally runs at 0.18 seconds without the above properties. Apart from `show tables`, rest of the commands not giving any output i.e. they keep on running until and unless I kill the process. Could you tell me reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Hive is not an RDBMS. A query that ran for 2 mins may run for 5 mins under the same configuration. Neither Hive nor Hadoop guarantee us about the time taken for a query to execute. Also, please include information about whether you are running on a single node cluster or multi node cluster. And also provide information about the size of data on which you are querying. The information you have provided is insufficient. But, don't come to any conclusion based on time to execute query. Because, lots of factors such as disk, CPU slots, N/W etc etc., are involved in deciding run time of query.